# DDD - Invalidating expirable

Tags: domain-driven-design

Currently diving into DDD and i've read most of the big blue book of Eric Evans. Quite interesting so far :)

I've been modeling some aggregates where they hold a collection of entities which expire. I've come up with a generic approach of expressing that:

```
public class Expirable<T>
{
    public T Value { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime ValidTill { get; protected set; }

    public Expirable(T value, DateTime validTill)
    {
        Value = value;
        ValidTill = validTill;
    }
}
```

I am curious what the best way is to invalidate an Expirable (nullify or omit it when working in a set). So far I've been thinking to do that in the Repository constructor since that's the place where you access the aggregates from and acts as a 'collection'.

I am curious if someone has come up with a solution to tackle this and I would be glad to hear it :) Other approaches are also very welcome.

**UPDATE 10-1-2013:**

This is not DDD with the CQRS/ES approach from Greg Young. But the approach Evans had, since I just started with the book and the first app. Like Greg Young said, if you have to make good tables, you have to make a few first ;)

Comment: Nice pattern indeed, but do you have an example of what `T` would typically be in the "expirable invariant" scenario ? Where would you place the code that enforces the invariant ?

Comment: See my comment below for a example gist.

Comment: Your example only uses `UserSession` for a `T`. `UserSession` isn't an invariant in the DDD sense of the term - a business rule enforced by the Aggregate Root. Since you mentioned invariants, I was just curious to know how you implemented them with `Expirable<T>`.

Comment: `User` is the `T`. So `User` is the aggregate which maintains the enforcements of adding/removing/updating invariants (`IEnumerable<Expirable<UserSession>>`). Correct?

Comment: Well, sort of. You seem to imply that `UserSession` is an invariant while i think it's really an Entity. An invariant is something that cannot be changed *about* an object, not the object itself.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know that, do you know where I can find that in the big blue of Evans? :)

Comment: p. 128 "Invariants, which are consistency rules that must be maintained whenever data changes..." :)

Comment: Cheers :) Read it again and found another good explanation of invariants: http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/03/11/ddd-invariants-or-contextual-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been reading up on DDD with CQRS/ES (Greg Young approach) and found a great example on the MSDN site about CQRS/ES: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx

In this example they use the command message queue to queue a Expire message in the future, which will call the Aggregate at the specified time removing/deactivate the expirable construct from the aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple ways to approach this, but I, personally, would solve this using the Specification pattern.  Assuming object expiration is a business rule that belongs in the domain, I would have a specification in addition to the class you have written.  Here is an example:

```
public class NotExpiredSpecification
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Expirable<T> expirableValue)
    {
        //Return true if not expired; otherwise, false.
    }
}
```

Then, when your repositories are returning a list of aggregates or when performing any business actions on a set, this can be utilized to restrict the set to un-expired values which will make your code expressive and keep the business logic within the domain.

To learn more about the Specification pattern, see [this paper](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf).

Comment: Interesting thought, haven't thought of that! :) I've read the chapter about specifications. The problem with this solution is that you will have to load the complete NotExpired set in memory, not very efficient. On the flipside it opens some idea's to me to try out.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The specification approach doesn't mean you have to load everything, in fact, you should only be loading what you need.  The specification is merely so you can filter out the expired values within the set you're working with.  If there are values you don't need to load into memory, then your repository would be responsible for that filtering and that would happen when you load your repository.

Comment: That's correct indeed! I thought of that later when I was working on my InvalidateExpirable method (see above). I could refactor the "query" part out of that method into a specification. Makes the domain more elegant and expressive. I might do that later, but for now it's sufficient. Querying is not really the problem, the problem is where and when and to remove the invariants (performance wise this could be a issue I guess). Every time you fire up a Repository or at each method in the repository which returns data? (would be more error-prone)

Comment: Again, it depends on your context and how your repositories are structured.  But, with regards to performance, you should only load from the database exactly what you need, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a method to my abstract repository `InvalidateExpirable`. An example would be the `UserRepository` where I remove in active user sessions like this: `InvalidateExpirable(x => x.Sessions, (user, expiredSession) => user.RemoveSession(expiredSession));`.

The signature of  `InvalidateExpirable` looks like this: `protected void InvalidateExpirable<TExpirableValue>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<Expirable<TExpirableValue>>>> selector, Action<T, Expirable<TExpirableValue>> remover)`. The method itself uses reflection to extract the selected property from the selector parameter. That property name is glued in a generic HQL query which will traverse over the set calling the remove lambda. `user.RemoveSession` will remove the session from the aggregate. This way the I keep the aggregate responsible for it's own data. Also in `RemoveSession` an domain event is raised for future cases.

See: https://gist.github.com/4484261 for an example

Works quite well sofar, I have to see how it works further down in the application though.